# .NET: Why is nested class having generics declaring in outer class?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Because the Type.FullName is a bit ugly, I need to make my beautiful name constructor. But when I used `Type.GetGenericArguments()` I ran into one problem.

Generic `T` of outer class `C1` is always distributed to nested classes `C2` and `C3`.

```
class C1<T> {
    public class C2<T1, T2> {
    }
    public class C3 {
    }
}

typeof( C1<> ).ToString(); // C1`1[T]
typeof( C1<>.C2<,> ).ToString(); // C1`1+C2`2[T,T1,T2]
typeof( C1<>.C3 ).ToString(); // C1`1+C3[T]
```

Two questions:

- How to determine whether generic type came from outer class or not?
- What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: as for second question - you have separate instance of nested class for each specific generic type of outer class; for example, if you declare `static` variable in C3, it will be different instances for each type of `T`; so you indeed have `C3` parametrized by `T`

Comment: `IEnumerable<Type> GetLocalGenericArguments(Type t) => !t.IsNested ? t.GetGenericArguments() : t.GetGenericArguments().Skip(t.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments().Length);` .

Answer (score 1):

Type parameters are not "inherited" by nested classes in CIL. There, your class looks like this:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit C1`1<T> extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit C2`2<T, T1, T2> extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
    }

    .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit C3<T> extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
    }
}
```

Since the definition of a nested type does not actually depend on the parent type, the outer generic arguments need not be accessible to it, and so it was decided they must be repeated explicitly, like C# does, but there is support for languages that work in a different fashion (where `C1<>.C3` could be a concrete type).

Your question is then one of obtaining a C# type expression from a .NET type. You may have luck with [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypereferenceexpression.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_CodeDom_CodeTypeReferenceExpression__ctor_System_Type_), or simply assume that if the generic parameters of the nested type have the same name as those of the parent type, you can omit them when creating the string.

So, to reiterate, generic parameters cannot come from the outer class in .NET, that is merely C#'s behaviour. If you assume the class was created in C#, you can simply remove the parameters based on their names.

Comment: The wording here is very confusing.

Comment: @Enigmativity Which sentence?

Comment: All of them to be honest. I really don't understand most of what you're saying. It's just plain confusing.

Comment: You don't need to match the type arguments by name; if the parent type has _n_ type arguments, they will be the first _n_ type arguments of the nested type and in the same order.